# RequestedOrientation for Screen (Compose)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I need to change the orientation of the screen by button or by sensors. It is also necessary to prohibit the change of orientation up to a certain point.
To do this, I set activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED

At the moment when I need to allow the screen to flip, I set activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED

By clicking on the orientation change button, I set the activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, but in this case the orientation changes to Lanscape and immediately back as indicated at the beginning of the function`if (viewState.value?.cameraRatio == null) activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED else activity.requestedOrientation = screeOrientation`

Another problem is that if I set activity.requestedOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, then changing the orientation by sensors does not work after that.

I tried specifying activity.requestedOrientation =ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_LANDSCAPE but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?